# How to subscribe on the value changed control event of a UISwitch Using Rxswift

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I want to use `Rxswift` and not `IBActions` to solve my issue below,

I have a `UISwitch` and I want to subscribe to the value changed event in 
it,

I usually subscribe on Buttons using this manner

```
@IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!


myButton
    .rx
    .tapGesture()
    .when(.recognized)
    .subscribe(onNext : {_ in /*do action here */})
```

Does anyone know how to subscribe to `UISwitch` control events?

Comment: Does `yourSwitch.rx.value.changed.subscribe(onNext: ...)` work?

Comment: I tried it now, and it didnt

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found the answer Im looking for, in order to subscribe on and control event we should do the below :

```
@IBOutlet weak var mySwitch : UISwitch!

       mySwitch 
            .rx
            .controlEvent(.valueChanged)
            .withLatestFrom(mySwitch.rx.value)
            .subscribe(onNext : { bool in
                // this is the value of mySwitch
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: This now gives an error that mySwitch.rx.value is not recognised for some reason

Answer (score 11):

```
Below are some caveats you would use for UISwitch:

 1. Make sure the event subscribes to unique changes so use distinctUntilChanged
 2. Rigorous switching the switch can cause unexpected behavior so use debounce.

 Example: 

anySwitch.rx
.isOn.changed //when state changed
.debounce(0.8, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance) //handle rigorous user switching
.distinctUntilChanged().asObservable() //take signal if state is different than before. This is optional depends on your use case
.subscribe(onNext:{[weak self] value in
            //your code
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 7):

There are couple of ways to do that. But this one is how I usually do it: 
Try this out.

```
self.mySwitch.rx.isOn.subscribe { isOn in
            print(isOn)
        }.disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

I hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

Another would be subscribing to the `value` rx property of the `UISwitch`, like so:

```
mySwitch.rx.value.subscribe { (isOn) in
            print(isOn)
        }.disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

Now, as for your comment:

> this worked for me thanks , but I preferred subscribing on the control
>   event it self, not the value.

We could do this below, I'm not sure though if there's a better way than this. Since `UISwitch` is a `UIControl` object, you can subscribe to its `.valueChanged` event, like so:

```
    mySwitch.rx.controlEvent([.valueChanged]).subscribe { _ in
        print("isOn? : \(mySwitch.isOn)")
        }.disposed(by: self.disposeBag)
```

More info: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiswitch

Comment: this worked for me thanks , but I preferred subscribing on the control event it self, not the value

Comment: thanks for the effort bro, but I posted the solution and it worked by subscribe on the value changed event, check my answer

Answer (score 4):

The following code works for me, building on prex's answer. Please feel free to correct or suggest any improvements.

RxSwift/RxCocoa 4.4, iOS 12, Xcode 10

```
private let _disposeBag = DisposeBag()

let viewModel: ViewModel ...
let switchControl: UIControl ...

let observable = switchControl
    .rx.isOn
    .changed   // We want user-initiated changes only.
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .share(replay: 1, scope: .forever)

observable
    .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] value in
        self?.viewModel.setSomeOption(value)
    })
    .disposed(by: _disposeBag)
```

In this example, we are notified when the user (and only the user) changes the state of the `UISwitch`. We then update `viewModel`.

In turn, any observers of the `viewModel`, will be told of the change of state, allowing them to update UI, etc.

e.g.

```
class ViewModel
{
    private var _someOption = BehaviorRelay(value: false)

    func setSomeOption(_ value: Bool) { _someOption.accept(value) }

    /// Creates and returns an Observable on the main thread.

    func observeSomeOption() -> Observable<Bool>
    {
        return _someOption
            .asObservable()
            .observeOn(MainScheduler())
    }
}
```

...

```
// In viewDidLoad()

    self.viewModel
        .observeSomeOption()
        .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] value in
            self?.switchControl.isOn = value
            // could show/hide other UI here.
        })
        .disposed(by: _disposeBag)
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53479618/1452758

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on the answers above, only the simplest one worked below:

```
@IBAction func toggleSwitch(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    if(mySwitch.isOn) {
        //Do something
    } else {
        //Do something
    }
}
```